# How do I read all the .wav audio file in one folder using information from an excel sheet in Matlab?

Tags: excel, matlab, audio

Hi I have a question for Matlab programming, I want to ask if I am using Mac OS and I have placed all my audio files in the same folder as Matlab, how do I read all the `.wav` audio files? I want to automate the process.

Example:

Firstly, I have an excel sheet with the audio file name and information.

Secondly, I want to extract the audio file names from the excel sheet (first column) and put it into the `audioread` function in MatLab.

I need to use the following `audioread` function.

```
[y,Fs]=audioread('audio1.wav');
```

I want to read `audio1.wav` and do some calculations on it. After finishing the calculation, I will proceed to read `audio2.wav` and do the same calculation for it. Can you teach me how to do this and show me the code for this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In Matlab you can read xls files with [`readmatrix`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html). You are maybe best to export your spreadsheet of audio files to a [csv file](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/import-or-export-text-txt-or-csv-files-5250ac4c-663c-47ce-937b-339e391393ba) first.

With regard to organising the data, it would be easiest for the spreadsheet to contain the full pathname to the file (i.e. `/path/from/root/to/file.wav`)

So, say you had a `audio_files.csv` of file paths like

```
/path/to/file1.wav, file1data
/path/to/file2.wav, file2data
/path/to/file3.wav, file3data
```

You could read each file with something like

```
filename = 'audio_files.csv';
audio_file_list = readmatrix(filename);

for audio_file = audio_file_list(:,1) % so long as the first column is the file paths
    [y,Fs]=audioread(audio_file);
    % do something to y
end
```

Of course, the `% do something to y` will depend entirely on what you want to achieve.